# CSS-only Solution To An Autosizing Select

Tags: css, forms, width, html-select

By default, selects will adopt a width allowing for the widest option. In a situation with lots of short options and one long one, this leaves loads of whitespace when a short option is selected.

Is there any CSS-only way of having the select adopt the width of the selected option?

Answer (score 0):

At some point you will need JavaScript to get what you want. But I guess this might help you to some extent.
Check out the example at [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/cojexikoto/edit?html,css,output).

Basically it uses the focus selector for the dynamic width you want. I have given a fixed width to the select element, which then changes according to the longest option when the select element is focused.

**CSS**:

```
#mySelect { 
  width:70px; 
}
#mySelect:focus {
  width:auto;
}
```